# 'std::bad_alloc' on remote server only (travis-ci)

Tags: c++, travis-ci, bad-alloc

I have this weird 'std::bad_alloc' thrown only during my test using travis-ci servers. I have tested my code on several machines, with the same compilers options, and I don't call any external library (only standard c++11).

```
./convexhull ../examples/convexhull/instances/size100space10.csv 1
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
/home/travis/build.sh: line 45:  3957 Aborted                 (core dumped) ./convexhull ../examples/convexhull/instances/size100space10.csv 1
```

I am new to travis-ci, so my question may be or not unrelated to it, but I have no clue so far. However, it does not seem to be related to some syntax issue (since my code is build and executed)

Does anyone have an idea on what could be the cause of the bad-alloc in a similar context? Is there a quicker way than using valgrind with travis-ci?

Comment: You are probably trying to use more memory than what is allowed for you on travis-ci.

Comment: For a CI server and for testing purposes,, it's always a good idea to only use a small subset of daat. Especially if the data is large and causes lots of memory to be allocated.

Answer (score 1):

std::bad_alloc means that you requested to allocate data on heap but there was not enough memory. This can be direct request with `new` or indirect, like creating a very big std::vector. Note, that std::bad_alloc is rarely encountered for several reasons. First of all, by default linux always successfully allocates memory because real allocation is made when you try to access it (and program is terminated with OOM in such case). And second reason is that today we usually have enough RAM.

CI server is a special case. They have to provide reliable infrastructure that runs unreliable and untrusted code. So they have to put limits on processes preventing them eating too much resources. This particularly means that RAM usage is limited too and the limit is not very high. So you have to use less RAM in your tests. Probably you should reduce size of test data.

Comment: Thank you. I will not be able to test before a week, but I will try with a minimal exemple as soon as possible.